# error: 'e' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration

Tags: c++, templates, stl, iterator

I'm trying to overload operator << for printing only every two elements of STL containers. But I have an error during the compilation:

```
error: 'e' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
```

And here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, T const &e){
    for(e::iterator it = e.begin(); it != e.end(); it = it + 2){
        out << *it << " ";
    }
    return out;
} 

int main(){
    std::vector<int> v;
    for(int i= 0; i < 10; i++){
        v.push_back(i);
    }

    std::cout << v;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: replace `e::iterator` by `T::iterator`

Comment: Use `auto &&it`

Answer (score 4):

You have two issues here.

One is with `e::iterator`. You can't access a member type through an object, you need to use the type. Instead you should just use `auto it = e.begin()`. If you can't use C++11, then you'll need to use

```
typename T::const_iterator it = e.begin()
```

The `typename` is needed because the name is dependent on a template parameter, and the `const_iterator` is needed instead of just `iterator`, because the parameter is marked `const`.

However, your more egregious error is in making this overload in the first place.

```
template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, T const &e){
```

This declares an overload for `std::ostream` output for *any type*. This is sure to cause you a headache, and, sure enough, if you fix the first error, you get an ambiguous function call error when trying to output `" "`:

```
main.cpp:7:20: error: use of overloaded operator '<<' is ambiguous (with operand types '__ostream_type' (aka 'basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >') and 'const char [2]')
        out << *it << " ";
        ~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~
```

If you really want to make this work with every standard library container, I guess you check if something like `T::iterator` exists, and only have your overload enabled if that's true. Something like this:

```
template<typename T, typename = typename T::iterator>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, T const &e){
    for(auto it = e.begin(); it != e.end(); it = it + 2){
        out << *it << " ";
    }
    return out;
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b1ddc1cd7e941fa2)